# Creating new column that aggregates another column i Python DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Noob question, but I have column in Python DataFrame that I want to aggregate into a new column.
Also I'm trying to create a column that take n*(average value), and also a column for the difference.
How...?

Added link to picture of dataset to illustrate. **VERY** new to Python/Jupyter Notebook!
Thanks in advance!:) [image: dataset_image]

Comment: whta have you tried so far?

Comment: `df['n*avg'] = df['n'] *df['average value']`

Comment: Hi ombk! I've made a new column next to it but unsure how to make the aggregate formula to fill the new column with the data

Comment: From the image you shared, what columns do you already have in the df, and which new columns you want to add to the df?

Comment: Hi Mr. Singh! Yeah sorry if that was unclear. So I currently have the green column in my DataFrame, and I want to calculate and add the yellow ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
a = pd.Series([1, 2, 4, 6, 11])
cumsum = a.cumsum()
average_n = n* a.mean()
diff = -cumsum+average_n

df = pd.concat([n,a,cumsum,average_n,diff],axis=1)
df.columns = ["n","data","cumsum","average_n","diff"]
df
```